# function javascript does not work properly with the id of link

Tags: javascript, jquery, reveal.js

I created `confirmation message box` using [this plugin](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/build-a-popup-modal-window-using-the-jquery-reveal-plugin/) .

```
<input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete All" />
<input type="button" id="deleteByID" value="Delete Item By ID" />
```

When I click on each button, it called the `callMessageBox()` to generate the message box and the id of message box is dynamic by the button name. After `message box` was call, the `actionOnMsgBox` executes in order to call the `callback function`.

```
$('#delete').click(function(){
     callMessageBox('delete','Are you sure to delete all items from your cart?','Yes','No');
});
actionOnMsgBox('delete',deleteAllItemInCart);

$('#deleteByID').click(function () {
    callMessageBox('deleteByID','Are you sure to delete this item from your cart?','Yes','No');
});
 actionOnMsgBox('deleteByID',deleteItemInCart,item1);
```

These are my functions:

```
 function messageBox(btnID, heading, confirmMsg, cancelMsg){
   var box = ' <div id="modal"><div id="heading">'+heading+'</div><div id="content"> <a href="#" id="'+ btnID + 'revealYes" class="button green close"><img src="images/tick.png">'+confirmMsg+'</a> <a href="#" id="'+btnID+'revealNo" class="button red close"><img src="images/cross.png">'+cancelMsg+'</a>';
   return box;
 }
 function callMessageBox(btnID, heading, confirmMsg, cancelMsg){
     if($('#modal').length == 0)
         $('body').append(messageBox(btnID,heading,confirmMsg,cancelMsg))
            $('#modal').reveal({
                 animation: 'fade',
                 animationspeed: 320,
                 closeonbackgroundclick: true,
                 dismissmodalclass: 'close'
            });
 }

 function actionOnMsgBox(btnID,callback,item){
     $(document).on('click','#'+ btnID +'revealYes,#'+ btnID +'revealNo',function (e) {
        var choice = $(e.target).attr('id');
        if ($(this).attr('id') == btnID + 'revealYes'){
            if(typeof item === 'undefined'){
                callback();
            }else{
                callback(item);
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
 }
```

Problem : when I clicked on `Delete All` button, then the `messageBox()` generated `deleterevealYes` and `deleterevealNo`. But when I clicked on `Delete Item By ID` the `messageBox()` still generated `#deleterevealYes` and `#deleterevealNo`, what I expected, it should be `#deleteByIDrevealYes` and `#deleteByIDrevealYes`.

Any idea what could be causing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the below functions. Give unique id for reveal function. If same id is given, the first one will be executed always

```
function messageBox(btnID, heading, confirmMsg, cancelMsg){
   var box = ' <div id="modal'+btnID+'"><div id="heading">'+heading+'</div><div id="content"> <a href="#" id="'+ btnID + 'revealYes" class="button green close"><img src="images/tick.png">'+confirmMsg+'</a> <a href="#" id="'+btnID+'revealNo" class="button red close"><img src="images/cross.png">'+cancelMsg+'</a>';
   return box;
 }

 function callMessageBox(btnID, heading, confirmMsg, cancelMsg){
     if($('#modal'+btnID).length == 0)
         $('body').append(messageBox(btnID,heading,confirmMsg,cancelMsg))
            $('#modal'+btnID).reveal({
                 animation: 'fade',
                 animationspeed: 320,
                 closeonbackgroundclick: true,
                 dismissmodalclass: 'close'
            });
 }
```

Comment: It has a problem with my `#modal {` css, if put `$('#modal'+btnID)` :/

Comment: If you have css problem, add class to '<div class="modal" id="modal'+btnID+'">'.. In css change #modal to .modal

Answer (score 1):

i believe if($('#modal').length == 0) is causing your problem
you only appending one div for all elements and skip the ones for particular ID